# Regex to match 2 or more words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a regex that tries to match for 2 or more words, but it isn't working as it's suppose to. What am I doing wrong?

```
$string = "i dont know , do you know?";
preg_match("~([a-z']+\b){2,}~", $string, $match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Expected Result:**

Array ( i dont know )

**Actual Result:**

Array ( )

Comment: try preg_match_all, instead.  And toss the `{2,}`

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I actually don't need the $match, I just need to use the preg_match in an if statement, so I'm not sure what difference preg_match_all would do.

Comment: Then why are you matching the words? when you should be counting the spaces instead.

Comment: If you need more than 2 words, why don't you match everything until `do you know?`?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Because people can type however many spaces as they want, doesn't mean it's that many words. Also, I'm trying to match words per punctuation. 2 or more words per single punctuation.

Comment: @frosty - then use preg_match_all, like I said before.  And see my answer.  There is a reason there is preg_match_all, to match all occurrences of pattern not one.

Comment: how about using a built in function that does exactly that, http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Comment: @AlexAndrei: yes, but this function isn't able to make the difference with a word that contains a single quote like `don't`, `O'Neil` and a field like this `# ' % @ '' " $ { []`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will match for string that contains exactly 2 words or more:

`/([a-zA-Z]+\s?\b){2,}/g` you can go http://www.regexr.com/ and test it

PHP:

```
$string = "i dont know , do you know?";
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z]+\s?\b){2,}/", $string, $match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match);
echo "</pre>";
```

Note: do not use the /g in the PHP code

Comment: Ooops. And you are absolutely right about the scaping, is my cripple IDE showing it as error. And yes the pattern is missing the \b. Updated the Answer. It should be right now. Thanks

Comment: It's better. Don't forget to remove the capture group around `[a-zA-Z]`. Test your patterns with www.regex101.com to know the number of steps needed for the regex engine (this gives an idea of the complexity of a pattern, the debugger is useful too). If you want to improve your pattern, search about how to "unroll a loop".

Comment: I doubt the `g` modifier is valid in php, javascrit yes php not so much.  http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php,  http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/frL

Answer (score 0):

This one should work: `~([\w']+(\s+|[^\w\s])){2,}~g`, which also match string like `"I do!"`

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/tH7uP6/1)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing how the `{}` are used, to match two words

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z]+)/i', 'one two', $match );

if( $match && count($match[1]) > 1 ){
         ....

}
```

Match is

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'one',
    1 => 'two',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'one',
    1 => 'two',
  ),
)
```

Match will have all matches of the pattern, so then its trivial to just count them up...

When using

```
        preg_match('/(\w+){2,}/', 'one two', $match );
```

Match is

```
 array (
      0 => 'one',
      1 => 'e',
 )
```

clearly not what you want.

The only way I see  with `preg_match` is with this `/([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+)/`

preg_match `([a-z']+\b){2,}`  http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/frM

preg_match `([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+)` http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/frO

Suggested

preg_match_all `([a-z]+)` http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/frR  ( may have to select preg_match_all on the site )

Comment: Down vote with not explanation?  It answers the question.